# How to insert from a textarea with auto line-break

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline, line-breaks

I want to create a post system on my site.

The source is an HTML textarea value, which is inserted in a MySQL database and displayed like this:

```
<div align='center' style='background-color: #FFFFFF;text-align:left;width: 500px;padding: 10px;border-top: 5px solid #F45144;'>
<center><h1 style='color:#F45144;margin-top: -10;'>$Title</h1></center>
<p>
$Post
</div>
<br>
<style>br{line-height: 600%;}</style>
```

But The text isn't formatted correctly.
(The "$Title" and "$Post" are 2 variables from database)

Look at the images:
When I insert a post like this:
[image]

I get this:
[image]

When I insert a post like:
[image]

The results are like:
[image]

I want to insert like in img1 and get a result like in img4. (without the need to insert a `<br>`)

Comment: you may accept an answer if it helped you. This helps the people doing your brain-work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to convert the text's newlines to the `<br />` tag,
you can achieve this by using the [nl2br()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function:

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

Comment: @Mikey You are welcome, and by the way, you need to escape your posts, don't post them without escaping the HTML or a hacker can print malicious code, if you find this answer helpful feel free to approve it and close the question.

Comment: But it is a very big space between the lines

Comment: Probably because you have too many newline characters, what all this function does is add a `<br />` before all newline characters.